# How to pass make flags stored in text files in command line?

Tags: shell, gnu-make

I have a text file called OPTIONS.txt storing all flags of Makefile:

```
arg1=foo arg2="-foo -bar"
```

I want to pass all flags in this file to `make`. However,

```
make `cat OPTIONS.txt`
```

fails with `make: invalid option -- 'a'`. It seems that shell interprets it as:

```
make arg1=foo arg2="-foo -bar"
     ^argv[1] ^argv[2]   ^argv[3]
```

Is there any way to make it interpreted as:

```
make arg1=foo arg2="-foo -bar"
     ^argv[1] ^--------argv[2]
```

Comment: A dirty workaround: `bash -c "make $(cat OPTIONS.txt)"`

Comment: Do you control the format of OPTIONS.txt?

Comment: @glennjackman Yes

Answer (score 1):

If you want the shell to interpret quotes after backtick expansion you need to use eval, like this:

```
eval make `cat OPTIONS.txt`
```

however just be aware that this evaluates everything, so if you have quoted content outside of the backticks you'll get the same issue:

```
eval make `cat OPTIONS.txt` arg4="one two"
```

will give an error.  You'd have to double-quote the `arg4`, something like this:

```
eval make `cat OPTIONS.txt` arg4='"one two"'
```

In general it's tricky to do stuff like this from the command line, outside of scripts.

**ETA**

The real problem here is that we don't have a set of requirements.  *Why* do you want to put these into a file, and *what* kind of things are you adding; are they only makefile variable assignments, or are there other make options here as well such as `-k` or similar?

IF the OP controls (can change) the format of the file AND the file contains content only used by make AND the OP doesn't care about the variables being command line assignments vs. regular assignments AND there are only variable assignments and not other options, then they can just (a) put each variable assignment on its own line, (b) remove all quotes, and (c) use `include OPTIONS.txt` from inside the makefile to "import" them.

Comment: It looks like `$(file < filename.txt)` is very unpopular - is there a reason not to use it due to some (to me) unknown caveat?

Comment: I don't know what that syntax is supposed to do.  Do you mean `$(< filename.txt)`?  How does that help the problem?  There's nothing wrong with it per se except it's not portable to other shells than bash, so I wouldn't use it inside a script or a makefile, but it's fine to use at the shell prompt if you want.  However, it has exactly the same issues as the `cat` version above.

Comment: I was referring to [the file function inside GNUmake](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Function). I thought it appropriate because the question came tagged "gnu-make". This function has the charming property to preserve line breaks, at least in my version of `make`. Of course this only works for variable contents, not the other flags. But it looks like this is the true intent of the OP.

Comment: Oh I see.  But the OP wants to read variable assignments from a file and add them to the command line of make.  It will be very difficult to use make's `file` function to reproduce this behavior.  First, you will need to use `eval` or similar to turn the file's variable assigments into make variable assignments.  Second, variables on the command line take precedence over variables in a makefile so you'd need to add `override` if this was needed, which will be very tricky.  And third, the file has quotes that the OP expects the shell to remove: removing them in make will be very hard.

Answer (score 1):

Since you control the options file, store the options one per line:

```
arg1=foo
arg2="-foo -bar"
```

Then in the shell, you'll read the file into an array, one element per line:

```
readarray -t opts < OPTIONS.txt
```

Now you can invoke make and keep the options whole:

```
make "${opts[@]}"
```

Comment: that *may not* work, because it will pass arg2's double quotes as literal characters. If make complains, store the line without quotes: `arg2=-foo -bar`

Comment: Note when you say "the shell" here you mean bash.  This won't work with other POSIX shells as it uses bash-specific features.